# How to set express.cookieSession to a path according to the incoming req.url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have a server written in node.js. it uses passport to log in users. i am also using express.cookieSession.

I have a few clients, each have its own folder (which suppose to server a few copies of my app to each client). each copy of my app will be accessed like this:

www.mysite.com/client1/...
www.mysite.com/client2/...

this is my server code:

```
app.configure(function() {
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.logger({format: 'dev'}));
app.use(basic.middleware);
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app'), { maxAge: oneYear}));
app.use(express.cookieSession(
    {
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || "cantbedecrypted",
        cookie: { maxAge: 1000*60*60 }
    }));
});
```

my goal is that according to this "client1" or "client2", i want to save a session cookie so that when I do req.log it will populate that specific cookie.

I have done this on the req.login function but the problem is that every time a user enters the site, it first creates a session cookie at path '/' and after the user logs in it creates another session cookie but this time on the desired path: '/client1/.

this is the code that saves the session cookie when logging in:

```
req.session.cookie.path = '/' + clientName;
```

the problem is when I do req.logout(), the session cookie that is being destroyed is on the default path : '/' and thus the user is stayed logged in.

is it possible to insert some middleware that will check the req.url before creating the initial session cookie so that it will be only saved on the "/client1/ instead on the default '/'?.

I just need a skeleton. I have tried something like this, just after the app.use express.cookieSession

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
check url...
req.session.cookie.path = **desired path
}
```

but this didn't work.

Is there a way I could use some parameters or global variables inside express.cookieSession? this could solve my problem.

Comment: Where are you calling req.logout? The url which calls req.logout must also reset the cookies for all possible paths.

Comment: How can i tell this req url to delete a specific cookie? The req.logout is done on a api route for logout. Very straight froward. How can i tell req.logout to also clear all the other cookies that were not set on the default path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up `req` and `res`. You don't modify `req` to send/set cookies, you change `res`. To reset cookie use [clearCookie](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.clearCookie). You can give path with it:

```
res.clearCookie('name', { path: '/admin' });
```